# Show Only browser version in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var N = navigator.appName, ua = navigator.userAgent, tem;
    var M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?d+(\.\d)*)/i);
    if (M && (tem = ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i)) != null) M[2] = tem[1];
    M = M ? [M[1], M[2]] : [N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
        document.write(M);
```

Gives me the output:

Chrome,24.0.1312.56

I was wondering if it was possible to show only the version type so like this:
 24.0.1312.56

I Don't know how to do this with this code i found it on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `document.write(M);` to `document.write(M[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using this method: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;

var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 


// In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
}
// In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
}
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < 
      (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) 
{
fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);

}
// trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
}

document.write(''
+'Full version  = '+fullVersion+'<br>'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE:

```
"use strict";
var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            var dataProp = data[i].prop;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
            else if (dataProp)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index == -1) return;
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Chrome",
            identity: "Chrome"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Apple",
            identity: "Safari",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            prop: window.opera,
            identity: "Opera",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Firefox",
            identity: "Firefox"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "MSIE",
            identity: "Explorer",
            versionSearch: "MSIE"
        }
    ],
    dataOS : [
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Win",
            identity: "Windows"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Mac",
            identity: "Mac"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Linux",
            identity: "Linux"
        }
    ]

};
BrowserDetect.init();

alert("*Browser: " + BrowserDetect.browser);
alert("*Version: " + BrowserDetect.version);
```